# Periodic tasks in Vala

Tags: vala

How can I create a periodic task in Vala? Is there any timer class in Vala that can call a scheduled method at a specified periods? If yes, please provide a sample code.

**Update:**

this is the sample code based on the answer and comments:

```
public class Sample : Object
{
   private static bool task()
   {
      stdout.printf("Yay\n");
      stdout.flush();
      return true; // false terminates timer
   }

   public static int main(string[] args)
   {
      Timeout.add_seconds(1, task);
      new MainLoop().run();
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a [TimeourSource](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.TimeoutSource) to a main loop. The return value of your callback decides if it gets rerun.

Comment: This is correct, but it's worth mentioning that most of the time you're probably going to want to use GLib.Timeout.add_full or GLib.Timeout.add_seconds which are convenience wrappers around GLib.TimeoutSource.

Comment: It is also noteworthy that for the task to be periodic (continued callbacks no just once) the callback should return true. please see the updated question